# Docker-compose volumes mode options

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

In the short syntax `source:target:mode` the official documentation only mentions `ro` and `rw` but in the [cookiecutter template for django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) they are using other two modes: `z` and `Z`, I didn't find any reference for them anywhere, What are they?

Answer (score 5):

The [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) documents:

```
-v, --volume=[host-src:]container-dest[:<options>]: Bind mount a volume.
The comma-delimited `options` are [rw|ro], [z|Z],
[[r]shared|[r]slave|[r]private], and [nocopy].
The 'host-src' is an absolute path or a name value.

If neither 'rw' or 'ro' is specified then the volume is mounted in
read-write mode.

The `nocopy` mode is used to disable automatically copying the requested volume
path in the container to the volume storage location.
For named volumes, `copy` is the default mode. Copy modes are not supported
for bind-mounted volumes.
```

These options are further documented in the [(named) volume documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume) (specifically `ro`) and [bind mount documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#use-a-read-only-bind-mount).

In practice I never need any of these options, except if I happen to be deploying to a system with SELinux enabled, then `z` is useful.

Comment: The specific documentation for "z" and "Z" is here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label